# Excel: How to concatenate a list produced by unique() with additional text following, in one cell

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, concatenation, unique

I have the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(H2:H1048576, H2:H1048576<>"")))&"_","Feedback",TEXT(TODAY()," mm.dd.yy"))
```

It is producing the following:
[image]

I want the call value to be "AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_Feedback 01.08.21". How do I do this?

Comment: Never use CONCATENATE. It is defunct, and has no real use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TEXTJOIN` instead of `CONCATENATE`. Also you don't need `FILTER` (you can ignore blanks with `TEXTJOIN`), nor `TRANSPOSE`.

```
=TEXTJOIN("_",TRUE,UNIQUE(H2:H1048576))&"_Feedback"&TEXT(TODAY()," mm.dd.yy")
```

[image]

Slightly shorter option (credit to @JvdV):

```
=TEXTJOIN("_",,UNIQUE(H2:H1048576),TEXT(TODAY(),"F\e\e\d\back mm.dd.yy"))
```

Comment: Adding that concatenate is unnecessary if you ask me, because using `&` in a function does that already.

Comment: I like it. A little shorter could be: `=TEXTJOIN("_",,UNIQUE(H2:H1048576),TEXT(TODAY(),"F\e\e\d\back mm.dd.yy"))`. But that's just...nonsense =)